# eclipse plugin special highlighting if test method is annotated with junit @Ignore

Tags: eclipse, junit, plugins, highlight

I was wondering if there is an Eclipse plug-in available that highlights JUnit test methods annotated with @Ignore (like strikethrough all characters that belong to the method). I tried it with Eclipse Settings, Preferences -> Java - > Editor -> Syntax Coloring (Java -> Annotations). It only allows to adjust the appearance for all annotations.

I don't know if I had enough sleep, but I was trying to execute one test method for a couple of minutes and was wondering why Eclipse does not jump into Debug mode. As I recognized that the test method was annotated with @Ignore.

If meta-information is provided, why don't use it :)

**Edit:**

I asked for this feature at moreunit [website](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3528334&group_id=156007&atid=798059).

Comment: I don't know of any plugin or setting that does this, but completely agree that it would be a very useful addition.

Comment: You could submit that as a feature request to the MoreUnit people; that seems to me like a plugin which could logically contain a feature like this.

Comment: @DavidWallace thank you for the suggestion, I will do this feature request.

Comment: If someone is working on this, is it possible to get a report of @Ignored tests along with the reasons in the "Problems" display?  Seems like a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature has been implemented by Vera Henneberger. I made a screen shot with my settings.
[image]